# RSpec test for handling known IP addresses

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to replace the array of ips with a method (like `known_ips` or just `ips`) but I don't know how.

I'll use this `known_ips` somewhere else.

```
describe WelcomeController, type: :controller do
  [
    {
      ip: '73.53.61.23',
      location_name: 'Seattle, Washington, US'
    }, {
      ip: '8.26.157.16',
      location_name: 'San Francisco, California, US'
    }, {
      ip: '174.112.13.21',
      location_name: 'Mississauga, Ontario, CA'
    }
  ].each do |params|
    it 'geolocalizes the visitor based on the ip' do
      allow_any_instance_of(ActionDispatch::Request).to receive(:remote_ip).and_return params[:ip]
      get :index
      expect(controller.current_location.name).to eq params[:location_name]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You should include your other code as well so that we can see what they have in common.

Comment: Since you are really asking for a solution to a problem and not a code review you should post this on Srack Overflow instead. In the spirit of code review, I would replace the very generic  `allow_any_instance_of(ActionDispatch::Request).to_receive` with `expect(controller.request).to_receive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'll use this known_ips somewhere else.

I'm guessing that "somewhere" will still be in a test file. If so you can put this in support file (which is a common patern in RSpec).

```
# spec/support/ip_list.rb
IP_LIST = [
  # easily to recognize that IP address is first and the location name the second, but you can use your code that uses Hash here
  ['73.53.61.23',   'Seattle, Washington, US'],
  ['8.26.157.16',   'San Francisco, California, US'],
  ['174.112.13.21', 'Mississauga, Ontario, CA']
]
```

Then on `spec_helper.rb` ([see this example](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/spec/rails_helper.rb#L25))

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
# after the last require
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
```

And in your actual test:

```
describe WelcomeController, type: :controller do
  it 'geolocalizes the visitor based on the ip' do
    IP_LIST.each do |(ip, location_name)|
      expect(controller.request).to receive(:remote_ip).and_return ip
      get :index
      expect(controller.current_location.name).to eq location_name
    end
  end
end
```

Note that I nested `IP_LIST.each` inside the `it` block, I don't think you need to create one `it` for each test. This is a personal opinion, I'm not sure what is the best practices here.